# WPF Custom ToolTip

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip, wpf-style

I am using .Net 4.7.2 and WPF 4.5.1

I created a custom control which I use as ToolTip. The custom control works and I can apply it to a UI control, a TextBox for example.

Unfortunately, I don't find a way, to get rid of the typical frame of the common tooltip, which reminds me of a Button.

But have a look

[ToolTip with a frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIQDv.jpg)

I've tried to override the default style of tooltips, like shown in several examples here on stackoverflow and other sites as well.

Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem.

My xaml code looks like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <local:MyToolTip Text="{Binding MyToolTipText}" />
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

How can I remove the button like border around the ToolTip?

Thanks in advance

**Clarification:**

I've tried two approaches:

first one:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">

    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"                        Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

                <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black">

                    <!-- other content -->

                </Border>


            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

second one:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyToolTip}">

    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"                       Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

                <local:MyToolTip />

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

The Custom Control does NOT derive from ToolTip, but from Control

```
public class ToolTip : Control
{
    // ...
}
```

As I mentioned already, there is no problem with the code of the control, I'm struggling with a styling problem.

Comment: "*I've tried to override the default style of tooltips*" - please show us what you've tried. Also show the relevant code parts of your control, especially whether it is derived from ToolTip or not.

Comment: @Clemens Please have a look at the clarification

Comment: Besides that it makes no sense to have `<local:MyToolTip />` in the Template of `MyToolTip`, you should have a default Style for `ToolTip`, as shown in the answer.

Comment: <local:MyToolTip /> in the template of MyToolTip was an attempt. It didn't work, so I don't use it anymore. The reason, why I use a seperate ToolTip class however is, that this class provides extra functionality. Again, there's no problem with the code of the class, but I need to fix the style issue.

Comment: Yes, I have. I am currently testing, if I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border comes from `ControlTemplate` of `ToolTip`. Change the `ControlTemplate` and you will get rid of border:

```
<TextBox Text="text box text">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="TEST" >
        </TextBlock>
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

So it looks out without and with `Style`:
[image]